# Script con docx-python no guarda el nuevo archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo el siguiente código el cual se encarga de mandar los datos al modulo `imprimir_ticket`:

```
from es import imprimir_ticket

def productos(self):
    lista_01 = [] 
    pago = self.Cantidad.text()
    if lista1 == []:
        QMessageBox.critical(None,"Error \n\n","Ningun elemento en la lista de ventas \t",QMessageBox.Ok)
    elif pago.isdigit() == False:
        QMessageBox.critical(None,"Error \n\n","El tipo de cambio no es valido \t",QMessageBox.Ok)
    else:   
        for i in lista1:
            self.producto_especifico_id(i,sucursal)
            if len(i) == 4:
                ref  =db.reference('/Productos_Bar')
                r11 = ref.get()
                for key in r11.items():
                    res = key[1]['id']
                    if res == i:
                        new_ref = key[0]
                        ref_s = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/'+str(new_ref))
                        r12 = ref_s.get()
                        for key in r12.items():
                            if key[0] == 'producto':
                                prod = key[1]

                            elif key[0] == 'precio':
                                prec = ' $'+key[1]

                        lister =[i,' ',prod,prec] 
                        lista_01.append(lister)
                        imprimir_ticket(lista_01)
```

y éste es el módulo que se encarga de generar el archivo:

**es.py**

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches, Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
import time
time = str(time.strftime("%H-%M-%S"))


def imprimir_ticket(lista_items):
    doc = Document()
    doc.add_heading('                   Grupo Exxe',0)
    for item in lista_items:
        parrafo = doc.add_paragraph(item)
        parrafo_formato = parrafo.paragraph_format
        parrafo_formato.left_indent = Pt(155)
        parrafo_formato.right_indent = Pt(155)

    doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/'+time+'.docx')
```

El problema es que al tratar de ejecutar de nuevo el script no genera el nuevo documento, solo genera un nuevo documento si cierro todo el programa y lo vuelvo abrir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que no genere el documento, es que lo sobreescribe porque el nombre es el mismo. Cuando se **importa un módulo el código en el espacio global** que no esté bajo `if __name__ == "__main__":` **es ejecutado en el mismo momento de la importación**.

Tu variable `time` es una **variable global** que es **inicializada en el momento que importas el módulo** (`from es import imprimir_ticket`) en el otro módulo, en **llamadas sucesivas a la función este valor será el mismo** mientras no se reimporte el módulo.

No hagas global esta variable (de hecho gasta mucho cuidado con las variables globales, solo deben ser usadas cuando realmente procede, por ejemplo constantes). En principio debería ser una variable local a la función de forma que cada vez que llames a la misma se actualize la hora y se cree el documento correspondiente con dicha hora.

```
from pathlib import Path
import time

from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches, Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT


def imprimir_ticket(lista_items):
    current_time = time.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    doc = Document()
    doc.add_heading('                   Grupo Exxe',0)
    for item in lista_items:
        parrafo = doc.add_paragraph(item)
        parrafo_formato = parrafo.paragraph_format
        parrafo_formato.left_indent = Pt(155)
        parrafo_formato.right_indent = Pt(155)

    doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save(Path("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/").joinpath(current_time).with_suffix(".docx")))
```

Obviamente, al cerrar y volver a ejecutar el programa se vuelve a importar el módulo, se crea de nuevo la variable `time` y se incializa con la hora actual, por lo que la primera llamada a la función no da problemas (quitando que la hora será la de la inicialización del programa, no la de la llamada a la función).

Algunas observaciones:

- No se pasan datos al otro módulo, importas el módulo y usas una función definida en el.
- `time.strftime` ya retorna una cadena, no es necesario el casting.
- Por otro lado, `time` es un muy mal nombre para una variable cuando está importando el módulo `time` con `import time`... Estás enmascarando el módulo recien importado con tu variable, a partir de ese momento el identificador `time` no hace referencia al  módulo `time`, es una cadena... En una posible segunda llamada a `time.strftime` nos encontraremos con un `AttributeError`.